# Is a typeorm @ViewEntity the same as postgres virtual table?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

Is a typeorm @ViewEntity the same as postgres virtual table? In other words, does it create a virtual table in the database itself and also all the features that comes with a virtual table?

Answer (score 0):

From `@ViewEntity()` documentation:

> This decorator is used to mark classes that will be an entity view.
> Database schema will be created for all classes decorated with it, and Repository can be retrieved and used for it.

- [More detailed ViewEntity documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/view-entities.md)

---

So, as I understand it's not exactly the same

Comment: That's what I thought too, someone had a similar problem (from typeorm issues): https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5984 basically saying that a view was not created in postgres. I just wanted to check.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a simple `Question` view using the `@ViewEntity()` decorator and I can confirm that the view works on Postgres and was recognized by pgAdmin.

[image: View screenshot here].